# login issue with Laravel and Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, sanctum

I have an issue with the login, I'm pretty sure to enter the good login information but I have the error message 401 i DONT understand why please someone help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSc5L.png)
I expect to understand why i have the bad answers even I enter the good login information.

Comment: what's the record of this user looks like in database ?, can you show us, or show us at least the signup code.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this code, I wouldn't check !Auth and it could be your front end passing the data incorrectly.

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    // Check email
    $user = User::where('email', $fields['email'])->first();

    // Check password
    if(!$user || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $user->password)) {
        return response([
            'message' => 'Incorrect Credentials'
        ], 401);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('mytokenstring')->plainTextToken;

    $response = [
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token
    ];

    return response($response, 201);
}
```

If you want to check data coming from front end you can put the below code in the controller and it will appear in storage-laravel log:

```
info($request->all());
```